# sql oracle: Listing Records that has a value repeated more than N number of times within the same month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am suppose to fetch from my records, if there is more than three records with the same Tradename stored within the same month.

An example of the record I have

```
TradeID      Tradename           PrescDT
------------------------------------------
1109         Panadol             sysdate-1
1123         Opioids             sysdate-3
1125         Doxycycline         sysdate-3
1138         Panadol             sysdate-14
1139         Panadol             sysdate-3
1141         Panadol             sysdate-5
1142         Codeine             sysdate-5
1162         Opioids             sysdate-14
1167         Codeine             sysdate-14
1168         Prednisone          sysdate-14
1170         Codeine             sysdate-21
1172         Codeine             sysdate-22
```

so it should return me with only this, where I only want the tradename and date

```
Tradename           PrescDT
------------------------------
Panadol             sysdate-1
Panadol             sysdate-14
Panadol             sysdate-3
Panadol             sysdate-5
```

I have tried using this but the returns me with all the records repeating at least thrice within the same month and it's not what I'm looking for

```
SELECT Tradename, PrescDT
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(PrescDT, 'MM')) AS c 
    FROM PRESCRIPTION p
    ) p
WHERE c > 3
ORDER BY prescDT ASC;
```

Comment: SELECT Tradename,PrescDT FROM my_table GROUP BY Tradename HAVING COUNT(*) > 3

Comment: `Codeine` also appears 4 times. Why is it not there in your expected result?

Comment: @PavanKumarTS How are you selecting `PrescDT` without having it in `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is almost right. You need to include the tradename into the `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
SELECT Tradename, PrescDT
FROM (
    SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Tradename, TRUNC(PrescDT, 'MM')) AS c 
    FROM PRESCRIPTION p
    ) p
WHERE c > 3
ORDER BY prescDT ASC;
```